# Прошивка Atmega32U4 скетчем arduino с внешнем кварцем на 16000

Tags: arduino, микроконтроллеры, avr, прошивка

Как прошить arduino Atmega32U4 с внешнем кварцем, не используя bootloader?
Я понимаю надо просто залить скомпилированный .hex через avr dude в Atmega32U4, используя обычный USBASP. Если надо поменять фьюзы подскажите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Загрузить IDE и скомпилировать скетч Примеры, Basics, Blink под плату Arduino Leonardo.
2. Найти в каталоге /tmp (в Linux) файл Blink.ino.with_bootloader.hex.
3. Подключить программатор к плате через разъём ICSP.
4. Проверить FUSE-биты с помощью avrdude. У Arduino Leonardo они следующие: hfuse 0xD8, lfuse 0xFF, efuse 0xCB.
5. Прошить контроллер скетчем командой

`avrdude -p m32u4 -c usbasp -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -Uflash:w:Blink.ino.with_bootloader.hex`

6. Отключить программатор от платы.